# Modify android keyboard to take "http://" or "https://"

Tags: android

I have an EditText that takes URLs from user as input. When the user clicks on the EditText, I want the http:// or https:// to show in the keyboard as an option input. How do I modify the keyboard? Is IME an option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I modify the keyboard?

You don't. It's not your keyboard. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of input method editors available for Android, both pre-installed on devices and available for download from the Play Store or elsewhere. None of them are modifiable from an SDK app.

> Is IME an option?

Not realistically. It's a lot of work, and approximately zero users will use yours.

If you want to simplify the data entry of the URL, you can:

- Cook up a `CompoundButton` that works a bit like `ToggleButton`, but toggles between `http` and `https`, and put that before the `EditText` for the rest of the URL, or
- Cook up a `TransformationMethod` to automatically put the scheme on the URL in terms of what the user sees in the `EditText` (the way `PasswordTransformationMethod` converts what the user types in into a bunch of dots), with a separate `Switch` or `CheckBox` to indicate whether or not the scheme should be `http` or `https`, or
- Just be flexible in terms of what the user types in. Either they type in a scheme, or they don't and you need to add one yourself. In either case, try the URL with an `https` scheme (for security), and if that fails, try the URL with an `http` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to modify the buttons on an existing keyboard. You are right, you would have to create your own keyboard (IME). However, this may be overkill for you as the user would have to go into settings to enable the new keyboard.

What you can do, is instead have a drop down next to your `edittext` with those options.

Or, maybe some sort of toggle button that allows them to specify.